# Trying to add a new field to solr collection removes the record?

Tags: php, xml, curl, solr

I have been struggling to simply add a new field to an existing solr collection and add data to it. In short, when I update the document, the record I'm trying to change disappears from search results.

I'll give a little background, then explain further. First of all, I am using solr version `3.4.0`, and I am updating the collection via a php script.

I added my new field to `schema.xml`; I should note that there are many other fields that already exist. My new field looks like this:

```
<field name="vocabularies" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

After I added the field to `schema.xml`, I restarted the solr server, and then started seeing my new field in the solr admin schema browser. So far so good.

Moving on to my php script, my curl options are below.

```
$options = array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://10.156.10.21:8983/solr/mycollection/update',
  CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: text/xml',
  ),
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_POST => 1,
  CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $update_query,
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The `$update_query` variable is populated with something like this:

```
       <add>
        <doc>
          <field name="id">id55328</field>
          <field name="title">MyRecord</field>
          <field name="description">My description.</field>
          <field name="author">Winston</field>
          <field name="image_link">http://mydomain.com/my/image/path/image.jpg</field>
          <field name="link">http://www.mydomain.com/my-url</field>
          <field update="add" name="vocabularies">12</field>
          <field update="add" name="vocabularies">24</field>
        </doc>
      </add>
```

The `id` field is the `uniqueKey` field. After this `POST` is sent, I send another `POST` with the same curl configuration as above, except the `$update_query` variable is replaced with `'<commit/>'`.

Now, when I run my php script, nothing changes. To see if it could be a problem with my php curl setup, I tried running the `POST` from [Dev HTTP Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dev-http-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?hl=en).

I set the request type to `POST`, added a `Content-Type: text/xml` header, and sent the same `xml` as the the `$update_query` variable contained above.

I got back the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">2996</int>
  </lst>
</response>
```

I sent the `<commit/>` `POST`, then checked my search results, and the record I was expecting to change had vanished from the search results. I checked the total amount of solr records in the database, and that number had not changed. Then I checked my new field in the solr admin schema browser, and the `term` and `frequency` counts had been updated, reflecting my change.

The search query structure I am using is this:

```
http://10.156.10.21:8983/solr/mycollection/select?q=*&start=50&rows=25&fq=sID:1&fl=nid+author+description+id+image_link+link+title+vocabularies&qt=&wt=&explainOther=&hl.fl=
```

So my question is, what is wrong with my php curl implementation, and why is my `Dev HTTP Client` (effectively a curl GUI) request, while seemingly successful on some counts, seems to hide the effected record from search?

Any insight whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
If I query the `id` of the record I updated, I get the right one back, complete with the new field and the correct data I entered. So that worked! But it's still not appearing in the search results. Is it a problem with my search query? If so, why would it have to change if I simply added a field?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not committing your updated records.

Make sure you add

```
commit=true
```

So, maybe try to change the url to be something like this

```
http://10.156.10.21:8983/solr/mycollection/update?commit=true
```

Comment: I am not committing in the same request as my data request, but I do commit in a second request after, as mentioned above. Functionally, does it make a difference if I commit in one request or two?